# C# XmlTextReader: html entity replace

Tags: c#, html, xml, xmltextreader

I have xml file with TAG like this:

```
<Question>dzia&amp;#322;owa</Question>
```

I'm reading this file using XmlTextReader and for this TAG I get something like this:

```
dzia&#322;owa
```

How to replace html entity numbers inside my xml to get something like this: "działowa"?

Comment: Why is the content of your tag escaped twice? Fix the problem, if possible.

Comment: probably I'll have to make unescape the entities by name - after that - I'll have text like "dzia&#322;owa" and now - how to change entity number "&#322" to valid text 'ł'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only HTML entity in your sample is `&amp;`. You've then got some normal text that says `#322;`. You either want

```
<Question>dzia&amp;&#322;owa</Question>
```

which would give "dzia&łowa" (probably not what you want)

or

```
<Question>dzia&#322;owa</Question>
```

which would give "działowa"

Comment: &#322 is entity number for char 'ł'

I would like to get 'działowa'

Comment: @UGEEN: Yes, but in your question you *don't* have this entity - something has correctly encoded the special character as the HTML entity number, but then the ampersand (&) in the entity has been encoded again. You don't want this double encoding, you just need `&#322`, *not* `&amp;#322`.

Comment: I need first to decode &amp;#322 to &#322 and then decode &#322 to 'ł' char. 2-steps decoding i think - I don't see a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved part of the problem (encoding &#number; to char):

```
public static string EntityNumbersToEntityValues(string s)
        {
            Match match = Regex.Match(s, @"&#(\d+);", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            while(match.Success)
            {
                string v = match.Groups[1].Value;
                string c = char.ConvertFromUtf32(int.Parse(v));
                s = Regex.Replace(s, string.Format("&#{0};", v), c);
                match = match.NextMatch();
            }           
            return s;
        }
```